# MedicOne Datatables Returning Numerous Rows When One Expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, eloquent-relationship

I am attempting to build a data table with medicone livewire datatables

I have this relationship on my Account model

```
public function lastLoginUser(): HasOne 
{ 
 return $this->hasOne(User::class)->ofMany('last_login_at', 'max'); 
}
```

When I add this column to my data tables columns method I am returned four rows when the raw sql query only returns one row.

```
Column::callback('lastLoginUser.last_login_at', function ($lastLogin) 
{ return self::relative_time_format($lastLogin); 
}) ->label('Last Login') ->searchable()
```

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE last_login_at IN (
    SELECT MAX(last_login_at)
    FROM users
);
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?